# Why hashchange is working but not fully when manually triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, eventtrigger, hashchange

I'm using a hashchange to fire the below script.  The hashchange works just fine but when it's being used to triggering the haschange manually (so when some lands on the page without a hashchange), only `$('#gallery-two').desoSlide` is fired.  It ignores the rest of the script.

Any tips on what I may be doing wrong for it not to work on the manual hashchange but working fine a normally, when there's an actually a hashchange and this `$(window).on("hashchange.gallery", function ()` fires the full script.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
     $(window).on("hashchange.gallery", function () {

         $('#gallery-two').desoSlide({
             thumbs: $('#gallery-two li > a'),
             auto: {
                 start: true
             },
             effect: {
                 provider: 'animate',
                 name: 'roll'
             },
             overlay: 'none'
         });
     });
     $(window).trigger("hashchange.gallery");
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Ignore previous answer. The formatting threw me. It is already in the document ready event.

Comment: no worries TrueBlueAussie..thanks for trying :o)

Comment: Just looking through one of my own `hashchange` projects and I trigger the initial change exactly the same way you do... Does the `desoSlide` addin support initializing itself multiple times?

Comment: I am using the .desoSlide multiple times but running it just once, like the example produces the same results.

Comment: The script wasn't running fully when I triggered the hashchange manually.  So, I had to put a timeout on it to give it time to run.  If anyone else has any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(window).trigger( "hashchange.gallery" );
    }, 2000);

Comment: Hi @user3702971, I'm the desoSlide creator. You can call desoSlide once per element. To refresh a slideshow, use `$('elem').desoSlide('rebuild')` public method.

Comment: @sylouuu I give that a whirl for sure.

Comment: @sylouuu This is off the subject, but since you created desoSlide, which super by the way... Is there way to set an image width for the large images? So that if some of the images are different widths, they use a common width with auto height.  I've tried several different methods with no luck.  Using the anchor seems tricky on the width...Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Inkling Prefer GitHub issues. By default, the original size is used. Use CSS to set a fixed `width`, `.desoslide-wrapper img { width: 200px; }`